# Can't build wxPython 2.8.12.1 on CenOS 6

Tags: linux, build, wxpython, centos6

When trying to build, I get the following error.
I truncated all errors past not finding the include file.
What am I missing?

```
python setup.py build
WARNING: WXWIN not set in environment. Assuming '..'
Found wx-config: /usr/local/bin/wx-config
    Using flags:  --toolkit=gtk2 --unicode=yes --version=2.8
Preparing CORE...
Preparing GLCANVAS...
Preparing STC...
running build
running build_py
copying wx/__version__.py -> build-gtk2.unicode/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/wx
copying wx/build/build_options.py -> build-gtk2.unicode/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/wx/build
package init file 'wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub1/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub2/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'wx/tools/XRCed/plugins/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub1/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'wx/lib/pubsub/pubsub2/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'wx/tools/XRCed/plugins/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
running build_ext
building '_stc' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DSWIG_TYPE_TABLE=_wxPython_table -DSWIG_PYTHON_OUTPUT_TUPLE -DWXP_USE_THREAD=1 -UNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ -Iinclude -Isrc -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c contrib/stc/gtk/stc_wrap.cpp -o build-gtk2.unicode/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/contrib/stc/gtk/stc_wrap.o -pthread -O3 -pthread
contrib/stc/gtk/stc_wrap.cpp:2680:24: error: wx/stc/stc.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good start to this here. http://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html
I don't have a WXDIR variable. When I tried to run from the bld directory, it didn't work. So I tried again from the source directory. My configure line was much simpler.

```
./configure --with-gtk --enable-unicode
```

The key that I didn't understand before, was that if I wanted stc. I needed to compile and install it separately.

```
make 
make -C contrib/src/stc
sudo make install
sudo make -C contrib/src/stc install
```

The author's .make file with

```
make $* \
    && make -C contrib/src/stc $*
```

works well too.

Remember to also run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

If you need other contrib stuff, look in the contrib/src directory for what is available.

Then cd to the wxPython directory. The standard

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

appear to work.

After all of this, I still needed to set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib. I was then able run the application I was trying to install all along, which was ride, a GUI editor for robot-framework.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Saved my day. This is uttely badly documented, and yet it is the required path for installing a very standard application (Robot Framework) on a standard OS (Debian).

Answer (score 0):

The point of this exercise was to wxPython 2.8.12.1 on CenOS 6. I could not find a workable binary to install. After I build the project, I found an acceptable place to get the binary. I wish that http://www.wxpython.org/ would point to this location as well. The Extra packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) has this project and others here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL .
An easy way to install them is to:

```
# yum install epel-release
# yum install wxPython
```

The first adds epel-release to your yum repository. The second installs wxPython. The binaries on the wxPython web site require a different gcc shared library. Using this repository ensures a match.